# Merge sort on an Integer class

Tags: java, performance, sorting, mergesort

This is a specific case in merge sort.  I'm trying to do a merge sort on an array that's created using the Java `Integer` class.  My implementation is slow and therefore needs some modifications for better performance.  I believe the process where I copy the original items to two new arrays over and over again is slowing it down.

How do I merge sort without copying?  The sorting must be stable and both methods should return `Integer[]`.

```
private static Integer[] mergeSort(Integer[] a, int p, int q) 
{
    if (a.length <= 1) return a;

    int mid = (int)Math.floor((q-p)/2);
    Integer[] left = new Integer[(mid - p) + 1];
    Integer[] right = new Integer[q - mid];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++)
    {
        left[i] = a[index++];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
    {
        right[i] = a[index++];
    }

    left = mergeSort(left, 0, left.length-1);
    right = mergeSort(right, 0, right.length-1);
    return merge(left, right);
}

private static Integer[] merge(Integer[] a, Integer[] b) 
{
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;

    Integer[] result = new Integer[a.length+b.length];

    while (i < a.length || j < b.length)
    {
        if (i != a.length && j != b.length)
        {
            if (a[i].compareTo(b[j]) <= 0)
            {
                result[k++] = a[i++];
            }
            else
            {
                result[k++] = b[j++];
            }
        }
        else if (i < a.length)
        {
            result[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else if (j < b.length)
        {
            result[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }

    return result;
```

Comment: The algorithm looks correct to me. Merge sort requires you to split the array which doesn't really happen without copying to two new arrays at some point so I don't think that's your issue. You could try doing it with an int[] instead of an Integer[]. Java might like its primitive types better

Comment: Given that this is not a homework, why don't you just use the Arrays.sort() stuff? That is a merge sort. (Provided you convert array of Integers to array of ints, but that's just O(n), less than O(nlogn) merge sort.)

Comment: I can actually write two void methods for sorting ints but this question requires me to return an array of type Integer[].

Comment: @Jakub Zaverka: Arrays.sort is using quick sort.  I'm trying to compare it with my program.

Comment: @user1175946 Oh, good one, I thought they are using mergesort. Anyway, if you use `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`, then it is mergesort (just checked). You only need to provide an implementation of `Comparable<Integer>`, which should be trivial.

Comment: @Jakub Zaverka: Thanks, but I'd like to implement my own method for testing purposes..

Comment: It is possible to implement it without having to create new arrays all over and copying them. Everything can be done on the original array, the merge operation will require an n-long buffer. That should improve it significantly. I am currently on mobile, I will try to post some code later.

Comment: You could use 

    `Integer[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid + 1);
    Integer[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid + 1, a.length);`

although I doubt it would affect performance.

Comment: Hey, would that still be stable? I really appreciate if you can show me how it's done..

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29 the sort is stable "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n*log(n) performance."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was quite hard, but I figured it out. You can even pre-create the buffer with some value you know the mergesort will never exceed, and save some object creation overhead.

```
public class Mergesort
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
        array = mergeSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static int[] mergeSort(int[] a, int p, int q) 
    {
        if (q-p < 1) return a;
        int mid = (q+p)/2;

        mergeSort(a, p, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid+1, q);
        return merge(a, p, q, mid);
    }

    private static int[] merge(int[] a, int left, int right, int mid) 
    {
        //buffer - in the worst case, we need to buffer the whole left partition
        int[] buffer = new int[a.length / 2 + 1];
        int bufferSize = 0;
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        int leftHead = left;
        int rightHead = mid+1;

        //we keep comparing unless we hit the boundary on either partition
        while(leftHead <= mid && rightHead <= right){
            //no data in the buffer - normal compare
            if((bufferSize - bufferIndex) == 0){
                //right is less than left - we overwrite left with right and store left in the buffer
                if(a[leftHead] > a[rightHead]){
                    buffer[bufferSize] = a[leftHead];
                    a[leftHead] = a[rightHead];
                    bufferSize++;
                    rightHead++;
                }
            }
            //some data in the buffer - we use buffer (instead of left) for comparison with right
            else{
                //right is less than buffer
                if(buffer[bufferIndex] > a[rightHead]){
                    //we overwrite next left value, but must save it in the buffer first
                    buffer[bufferSize] = a[leftHead];
                    a[leftHead] = a[rightHead];
                    rightHead++;
                    bufferSize++;
                }
                //buffer is less than right = we use the buffer value (but save the overwriten value in the buffer)
                else{
                    buffer[bufferSize] = a[leftHead];
                    a[leftHead] = buffer[bufferIndex];
                    bufferSize++;
                    bufferIndex++;
                }
            } 
            leftHead++;
        }
        //now we hit the end of either partition - now we have only two of them (buffer and either left or right)
        //so we do traditional merge using these two
        while(leftHead <= right && (bufferSize - bufferIndex) > 0){
            if(rightHead <= right && a[rightHead] < buffer[bufferIndex]){
                a[leftHead] = a[rightHead];
                rightHead++;
            }
            else{
                if(leftHead <= mid){
                    buffer[bufferSize] = a[leftHead];
                    bufferSize++;
                }
                a[leftHead] = buffer[bufferIndex];
                bufferIndex++;
            }
            leftHead++;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I did not extensively test it, nor did I measure it. You can try that and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the only criteria that you want, then you can use threads to paralyze the merging part of it. To copy an array there is a simple way to use `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Here is the code that includes thread and the use of array as reference:

```
Integer[] array;

public MergeSort(Integer[] array) {
    this.array = array;
}

public void run() 
{
    if (this.array.length <= 1) return;
    int mid = (int)Math.ceil((this.array.length)/2.0);
    Integer[] left = new Integer[mid];
    Integer[] right = new Integer[this.array.length - mid];

    left = Arrays.copyOf(array, mid);
    right = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, mid, array.length);

    Thread t1 = new MergeSort(left);
    Thread t2 = new MergeSort(right);
    t1.run();
    t2.run();
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    merge(left, right);
}

private void merge(Integer[] a, Integer[] b) 
{
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;

    while (i < a.length || j < b.length)
    {
        if (i != a.length && j != b.length)
        {
            if (a[i].compareTo(b[j]) <= 0)
            {
                this.array[k++] = a[i++];
            }
            else
            {
                this.array[k++] = b[j++];
            }
        }
        else if (i < a.length)
        {
            this.array[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else if (j < b.length)
        {
            this.array[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Integer[] unordered = new Integer[]{12,1,34,22,13,54,2,6,3};
    MergeSort merger = new MergeSort(unordered);
    merger.start();
    merger.join();
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(merger.array));

}
```